# Get input values in laravel formRequests

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

This is my **FormRequest** class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use URL;
class CaseStudyUpdateRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
      $id = $this->request->get('cspid');
      dump($this);
      dump($id);
      $prev_url = URL::previous();
      $url_arr = explode('/', $prev_url);
      $data = $this->request->all();
      dump($data);
        $rules = [
            // 'post_title' => 'required|min:15|max:255|unique:case_study_posts,title,'.$id,
            'summary' => "required|array|min:1",
            'total_blocks' => "not_in:0",
            'category' => 'required',
            'specialities' => 'required',
        ];
        if($url_arr[4] === "edit-for-request") {
          // $rules['edit_comment'] = 'required';
                if(!empty($data)) {
                  $rules['edit_comment'] = 'required';
                    $totalBlocks = $data['total_blocks'];
                    foreach(range(1, $totalBlocks) as $i){
                        if(array_key_exists("description-$i", $data)) {
                          // $rules['edit_comment'] = 'required';
                            $rules["description-$i"] = 'required|min:15';
                        } elseif(array_key_exists("image-$i", $data) || array_key_exists("image_title-$i", $data) || array_key_exists("image_description-$i", $data)) {
                          // $rules['edit_comment'] = 'required';
                            $rules["image-$i"] = (array_key_exists("old-img-$i", $data) && !array_key_exists("image-$i", $data)?"":"required|mimes:jpeg,bmp,jpg,png|max:2048");
                            $rules["image_title-$i"] = "required_with:image-$i|required|min:5|max:30";
                            $rules["image_description-$i"] = "required_with:image_title-$i|required|min:15|max:120";
                        }
                    }
                }
        }

        return $rules;
    }

    public function messages() {
        return [
           'total_blocks'=> 'Please select text/images block to case studys',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get custom attributes for validator errors.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function attributes() {
        return [
            'post_title' => 'Case Study Title',
        ];
    }


}
?>
```

**View page**

In my view page I've this,

```
@section('scripts')
@parent
   {{ Html::script('vendor/jsvalidation/js/jsvalidation.js') }}
   {!! JsValidator::formRequest('App\Http\Requests\CaseStudyUpdateRequest', '#edit_post_form'); !!}  
   ....  
   ....
```

**Controller**

In Controller, I've added

```
use App\Http\Requests\CaseStudyUpdateRequest;
```

and in the called function

```
public function editCaseStudy(CaseStudyUpdateRequest $request) {
```

Here, i have image blocks and description blocks , say, image1, image2,image3,description1, description2,..etc.. 
I want to validate those fields, so i need to get those input values in formRequest file. But it's showing an empty array when i print `dump($this->request->all());`

How do i get input value in side formRequest?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest` class [extends](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php#L15) the `Illuminate\Http\Request` class. So `all()` or any of [the usual methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#retrieving-input) will give you access to the request parameters from GET or POST.

e.g. instead of this:

```
$id = $this->request->get('cspid');
```

Use one of these:

```
$id = $this->cspid;
$id = $this->get("cspid");
```

Comment: Ah.. may be. I couldn't figure what's wrong, Since it's not working i've done ajax validation

Comment: You can’t rely on client side validation. Are you type hinting the `CaseStudyUpdateRequest` object in your controller method?

Comment: Yes, I have added that in controller

Comment: I've updated my question, Please check. I'm using formRequest in all of my forms, but couldn't get id in any of my formRequest class

Answer (score 0):

In the formrequest class, rules() function:

```
$this->route()->parameter('myrouteparam')
```